# How to initialize a datetime.time object from a string?

Tags: python, datetime, time, strptime

Is there a method like `datetime.datetime.strptime()`, that accepts a string like `'16:00'` and returns a `datetime.time(16,0)` object (i.e., an object that holds only time, not date)?

Edit:
I could use datetime.datetime.strptime(), but it would return a datetime.datetime, and I want only time, not a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime
import time
def datetimestrptime(time_string,time_fmt):
     t = time.strptime(time_string,time_fmt)
     return datetime.time(hour=t.tm_hour,minute=t.tm_min,second=t.tm_sec)
print datetimestrptime("16:00","%H:%M")
16:00:00
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import time
time.strptime("16:00", "%H:%M")
```

Comment: it creates a `time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=16, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)`, not a `datetime.time`.

Comment: you can then use `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.strptime(...))`

Comment: @Joran, that would create a datetime.datetime object, and I need an object without a date.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative way is using `datetime.datetime.strptime()` and then extracting time from it.

```py
import datetime

def time_from_str(time_string, format):
     date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string, format)  # datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16)
     return date_time.time()
     
time_from_str("16:00","%H:%M")
# 16:00:00
```

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail:%7E:text=For%20the%20datetime.strptime()%20class%20method%2C%20the%20default%20value%20is%201900%2D01%2D01T00%3A00%3A00.000%3A%20any%20components%20not%20specified%20in%20the%20format%20string%20will%20be%20pulled%20from%20the%20default%20value.):
For the `datetime.strptime()` class method, the default value is `1900-01-01T00:00:00.000`: any components not specified in the format string will be pulled from the default value.